# Free database of vehicle data and images

Tags: data-request, transportation

I've been looking for a free database of vehicle manufacturer's specifications, data, and images for a long time with no luck, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: please expand. what kind of vehicles? trucks, cars, boats? and what kind of data? manufactor specs, reported fuel economy, crash test results?

Comment: Anything categorized as a "vehicle". More specifically, I'm looking for manufacturer specs.

Answer (score 10):

For the United States, [FuelEconomy.Gov](http://www.fueleconomy.gov/feg/ws/index.shtml) provides a seemingly comprehensive database of vehicles. You can use the API to pull down select vehicles or all vehicles in the database. In is primarily to communicate fuel economy, but a number of other vehicle features are also reported (transmission, engine type, etc.).

Full disclosure: I'm the developer of [an R package](https://github.com/rOpenGov/mpg) aimed at extracting data from the API.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a database of vehicles in the UK.

[How Many Left?](http://www.howmanyleft.co.uk)

> Search for statistics about every make and model of vehicle registered in Great Britain. Data comes directly from the Department for Transport, and is regularly updated.

Answer (score 4):

Edmunds API has pretty decent info.

http://developer.edmunds.com/api-documentation/overview/index.html

Comment: This is an old answer, but I found it today - just noting that Edmunds no longer offers this API to the public, only to car dealers and other strategic partners.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a quick and easy database of UK New Vehicles then The following may be of use:

http://www.keeresources.co.uk/data/free-vehicle-data/

It does not include images or technical data but may be a useful starting point.

Full Disclosure: I work for the company that produces this product.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a database of all the car models (~230k) sold in France](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/vehicules-commercialises@public/?tab=table&sort=puissance_maximale) since 2001, including power, consumption and greenhouse gaz emissions. There are no picture though. You can download the dataset or get the data via an API. The source is the [ADEME](http://www.ademe.fr/en), The French Environment and Energy Management Agency who run the tests.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You'll do well to find a free database. However, I found https://www.carmakesandmodels.co.uk offers a free API. I needed a solution for a car insurance website and found this API adequate and updated monthly.

Comment: One-time free quota is a paltry 20 requests, with no free replenishment after they are gone. I don't adhere to strict definitions of open data, but this is defintely not open data.

Answer (score 1):

I was once using Edmunds for an app. Haven't they closed their API?? (that's what i've heard).

I did use [cdbapi](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters/?=stackoverflow), too. We needed only few fields for integration,but the info was accurate.

Comment: Could you add a link to *Edmunds*, so that others can follow up on your comment easier? Also, please add one more sentence on what data/fields the cdbapi contains; finally, a notice would be in order that the latter - accordng to [cdbapi's terms and conditions](https://www.car-database-api.com/terms-and-conditions) - are definitely not *open* data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Autodata-net](https://www.auto-data.net/en/) (updated on a daily basis).

If you want more detailed technical data, check out [Car DataBase API](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters). It is a paid database, but it offers images with the cars.

Answer (score -1):

There's a pretty good/large vehicle make and model database free(not include images) and API(paid) : [Vehicle make model database download free](https://databases.one/#download).

Comment: conflicted as to downvote this or not, seeing as it is paid data.

Comment: There is free download of brands and car models (base version is free)