# Any APIs available that provide data of Indian vehicles?

Tags: api, india

I was looking for APIs that provide current latest data of vehicles (2-wheelers/4-wheelers) in India. I found quite a few but none had data of Indian vehicles. I [looked at this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/free-database-of-vehicle-data-and-images) which is almost same as mine but couldn't get any help either.

I found one website http://dataweave.in/apis/usage/15/Car-Prices-India which has some of the data I'm looking for but unfortunately, it is very old data and not really of much use to me.

Does anyone know any good API sites for Indian vehicles or APIs that provide Indian vehicle data too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want data about each actual vehicle? Or each type of vehicle?

Answer (score 2):

Yes below company is providing Indian vehicle details by API. But it is paid.

http://api.vibrantgujarat.org/

Comment: I just checked the site. Thank you for the information really. It's a good start but it doesn't seem to provide all the information required. However, just wondering, is that site still in Beta stage? Some of the links don't seem to work. And also the pricing seems high too. But this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following links:

https://vahan.nic.in/paidnrservices/

https://vahan.nic.in/paidnrservices/forms/paidnr_access_policy.pdf

Let me know if I misunderstood :(

Comment: Please do not write link-only answers. Quote the essential parts or describe how this answers the question.

Comment: conflicted about this answer...its not open, but still a solution....should probably take this to meta; currently just typing outloud

Answer (score -1):

I may be a bit late, but if you are somehow still looking for such data you may try with this [car-database-api](https://www.car-database-api.com) It's paid - but you can choose what kind of info you want - the parameters I mean.

Are you looking for a particular Indian brand? I think they have Mahindra, Maruti and Tata.

** You will not get Name of Owner using this API, or any information about Owner.

Comment: You have recommended this same database in 3 recent answers. Are you in any way affiliated with it? On Stack Exchange websites you *must* disclose affiliation.

Comment: no, i am not affiliated with them. just trying to be helpful, cuz i've been here before - my questions were never answered for years. i recommend what i have used - that's all. the funny thing is that i tried to edit my initial answers with other sources but was not permitted to publish the changes...

Comment: Thanks. I just edited this answer. Maybe it's this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122893/does-restricting-the-number-of-links-for-new-users-do-any-good and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5328/increase-the-number-of-links-new-users-can-post-in-answers